# Add multiple users, groups and groups permission from *csv file to SharePoint 2013 using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, powershell, script, csv

I am looking for script to add multiple users and multiple groups to SharePoint 2013. I have CSV file with cointains two columns with header **"user"** login and **"group"** name with are separated by `(;) as a delimiter`. There is more than `600 users` which are references to `82 different groups`. Script should also set permission **"read"** to all groups.

Thanks lot
Michal

Answer (score 3):

Just a five minute pseudocode, this should work...

```
add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

$SPWeb = get-spweb http://sharepoint/sites/sitecollection/subsite
$owner = "domain\adminuser"
$op = New-SPClaimsPrincipal $OwnerName -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
$owner = $SPWeb | Get-SPUser $op


$csvlocation = "c:\csv\users.csv"
$values = Import-Csv $($csvlocation)| Sort-Object group

$count = $values.Count
$groups = @()
for($i=0; $i -lt $count; $i++){

  $item = $values[$i]
  $groupname = $item.group
  if(!$group.Contains($groupname))
  {
    $SPWeb.SiteGroups.Add($groupname, $owner, $null, $null) 
    $SPGroup = $SPWeb.SiteGroups[$groupname]
    $groups += $groupname
  }

    $mem = New-SPClaimsPrincipal $item.user -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
    $member = $SPWeb | Get-SPUser $mem
    $SPGroup = $SPWeb.SiteGroups[$groupname]
    $SPGroup.AddUser($member)


}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike we are almost there however I get an error : 
New-SPClaimsPrincipal : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The a
rgument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then
try the command again.
At C:\Users\SpSetupUsr\desktop\Untitled1.ps1:5 char:29
+ $op = New-SPClaimsPrincipal $OwnerName -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
++ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-SPClaimsPrincipal], Parame
   terBindingValidationException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewClaimsPrincipal

Comment: Get-SPUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is
null. Supply a non-null argument and try the command again.
At C:\Users\SpSetupUsr\desktop\Untitled1.ps1:6 char:30
+ $owner = $SPWeb | Get-SPUser $op
+                              ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-SPUser], ParameterBindingV
   alidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Share
   Point.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetUser

Comment: my csv file looks like if that might help also :

column 1         |       column 2

user                          group
domain\user             HR
domain\user2           HR
domain\user3           LADP
...

Comment: is the header of your CSV column1 and column2 instead of group and users?

Comment: nope is "user" and "group" header

Comment: would be great if this code could also checking if user already exist as SP user

Comment: I changed my code to reflect "user" instead of "users", and this could also get you on the right track

Comment: I managed to chaned your code and some more features including setting  permissions to adding groups.

Answer (score 1):

powershell that iterate thru *.CSV file (with login and group names) and add multiple users, groups and group permissions as necessary.

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
Write-Host "Connect Sharepoint Cmd-Let" 
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
}

$Site = Get-SPSite https://mysharepoint
$Web = $Site.RootWeb

$ownerName = "DOMAIN\SpAdmin"
$op = New-SPClaimsPrincipal $OwnerName -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
$owner = $Web | Get-SPUser $op

$csvlocation = "c:\csv\users.csv"
$values = Import-Csv $($csvlocation) -Delimiter ";" 

$values | ForEach-Object {

#Checking this group already exist in SP   
if(!$Web.SiteGroups[$_.group] -eq $_.group) {

    #Adding Group and Set Permission
    $Web.SiteGroups.Add($_.group, $owner, $null, $null) 
    $SPGroup = $Web.SiteGroups[$_.group]
    $assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($Web.SiteGroups[$_.group])
    $role = $web.RoleDefinitions["Read"]
    $assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role);
    $web.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment)
}

#Adding User to Group
$SPGroup = $Web.SiteGroups[$_.group]
$SPGroup.AddUser($_.user,"","",$_.group) 

#Added User and Group listed on console 
Write-Host "User :" $_.user "added to Group " $_.group

}

$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to import a `.csv` file with following fields:

```
GroupName,Managed_by,PrimarySmtpAddress,Members
```

`Managed_by` and `Members` are columns (People and Group) and both have multiple users separated ";"

Kindly advise

Comment: Perhaps, this doesnot answer the question, you can raise a new question or post comments to the main question. Thanks