# SharePoint Permissions Access

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I am building a SharePoint website for a company. There are total above 3000 employee in the company. I need to give them permission to access the intranet.

How to do it?

I don't want to type each name in the permission box and give each access individually.

Is there any easier way out?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use **Everyone** or **Everyone except External Users** group in SharePoint to grant the permissions on your SharePoint site.

   But make sure you are not granting them higher permissions than they should have on your site.

   Ideally you should not give more than **Read** permission to this group or all users will be able to edit/modify lists items, documents, pages, etc in your SharePoint site.

   **Reference**: [How to grant all employees access to a SharePoint site via Everyone except external users Group](https://sharepointmaven.com/grant-employees-access-sharepoint-site-via-everyone-except-external-users-group/).
2. If you want to grant customized permissions to the users then you can create a **Group** in your SharePoint site and then add users (selected users, individually) to this group.

   **Reference**: [Customize SharePoint site permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions).

Also, you can read more about **Default permission levels and Everyone** in SharePoint in below article:

[Understanding permission levels in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/understanding-permission-levels).

Comment: Does this answers your question? If yes, please upvote and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

What environment do you use? SharePoint online or SharePoint server?

***SharePoint online :***

You can add multiple users to Office 365 in the Microsoft 365 admin center

1.Sign in to Office 365 with your work or school account.

2.In the admin center, choose Users > Active users.

3.Select Add multiple users.

More information:

[Add several users at the same time to Office 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/add-several-users-at-the-same-time)

***SharePoint server:***

I recommend you use powershell, you can refer to the commands provided in the two threads below:

[Add multiple users, groups and groups permission from *csv file to SharePoint 2013 using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165866/add-multiple-users-groups-and-groups-permission-from-csv-file-to-sharepoint-20)

[Add user to SharePoint 2010 group using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458392/add-user-to-sharepoint-2010-group-using-powershell)

In addition, if you know the users email addresses, you can add them in bulk, delimited by a semicolon.

user1@mycompany.com;user2@mycompany.com ...etc